# Testing Mean of Random Sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing

If $Y_1,..., Y_{n}$ are iid N($\mu$, $\sigma^2$) where variance is unknown and $Y_{n+1}$ was observed but one thinks that this has different mean from the n observations.

What kind of test can I use to test whether the new observation $Y_{n+1}$ has different mean from the rest?

Some hint will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like outlier detection.  Since you have estimates of mu and sigma from the first n samples you can look to see if Y(n+1) is many standard deviations away for the mean.  This could be seen as a shift or some might think it is an error.  Grubbs' test has optimality properties for normal data.  Dixon's ratio test is also effective for normal distributions but is also useful when the distribution of the Y_i s in non normal.  These tests are good when their is only one outlier.  If you have two outliers there is a masking effect.

Comment: One outlier can hide the other and you may wind up not detecting either.  In your set up there is only one.  To be complete some argue that instead of excluding data compute estimates  that keep the outliers but give them less weight.  This is a field called robust statistics.  Since you are not estimating parameters this also may not apply.  I can find references for you.

Comment: Here is one for Grubbs and one on this site that I gave an answer on Dixon's test. https://www.itl.nist,gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35h1.htm .

Comment: That was Grubbs here is Dixon: http://stats.stackexhange.com/questions/38105/dixon-test-and-normal-distribu.tion

Comment: I published a paper in the journal The American Statistician in the 1980s.  the title was  On the Robustness of Dixon's Ratio Test in small samples.

Comment: In the Grubbs  reference there is a typo. It should have read "stackexchange.com" in place of "stackexhange.com".

Comment: My paper appeared in 1982 under the title "A Note on the Robustness of Dixon's Ratio Test in Small Samples"  you can find it here: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1982.10482812 .

Comment: I am trying to link web pages at this site and others but have not been successful even when I give a complete correct address.  Can anybody help me?  Maybe a moderator?

Comment: Moses ... You could construct a prediction interval for $Y_{n+1}$ and conclude it wasn't consistent with the model used to generate the interval if it lay outside the interval.

Comment: @Michael ... I'm not sure what the difficulty is. I just paste in URLs and the site converts them to links. Sometimes (depending on how you generate the URL), you need to put "http://" or "https://" at the front of the URL so it will convert (i.e if you paste a URL in and there's no http bit, you can just type it and everything works)

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b I suspected that might help.  I have seen people use just one word like "here"  and it appears in red and links.

Comment: The Grubbs ref to the NIST site works on Google but not here.

Comment: Can you think of this as a statistical significance test, where your question is to find the probability of having the observation arise under that normal distribution? E.g. does it make sense to calculate the area under the normal distribution curve to obtain the area under both of the tails? This way you get something that looks like a $p$ value. Then if this $p$ value is too small, I think you may reject that the sample is from this normal distribution (implies possibly other mean) -- just some thoughts.

Comment: @Michael Oh, okay -- that's just how to make a link using Markdown (which is the markup language used by stackexchange). See [our editing help on inline links](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) or [John Gruber's own documentation for links in Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link). Questions like this should be placed on meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is not outlier detection,** because you have a definite hypothesis concerning *which* value is an outlier.  You simply want to see whether $Y_{n+1}$ is "consistent with" the $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$.  This is a job for a *prediction interval.*

A general formula for prediction intervals in an (asymptotic) regression setting, which generalizes this one, is given at [Relationships between two variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/913), but it is not explained.  The following indicates how a prediction interval can be developed and exposes some of the assumptions.  The correctness of this procedure is demonstrated with simulations, which also inform us about how well the procedure performs in various circumstances.

---

When all $n+1$ values are independently drawn from the same Normal distribution, it is clear (from standard theoretical considerations) that the prediction interval must depend on the ratio

$$X = \frac{Y_{n+1} - \bar Y}{s_Y}$$

where $$\bar Y = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$$ is the mean of the first $n$ $Y_i$ and $$s_Y^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \bar Y)^2$$ is their sample variance.  The three random variables $Y_{n+1}$, $\bar Y$, and $s_Y$ are independent (because, as is well known, $s_Y$ is independent of $\bar Y$ even though they are computed from a common set of variables).  The numerator of $X$ has a Normal distribution because it's a linear combination of Normal variables.  We may compute that its mean is zero and its variance is

$$\operatorname{Var}(Y_{n+1}-\bar Y) = \operatorname{Var}(Y_{n+1}) + \operatorname{Var}(\bar Y) = \sigma^2 + \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2 = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sigma^2.$$

As usual, $s_Y^2$ has a Chi-squared distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom (d.f.).  **Consequently $X$ is $\sqrt{1+1/n}$ times a variable having a Student $t$ distribution with $n-1$ d.f.**  Let $t_{\alpha/2,n-1}$ be the $\alpha/2$ quantile of that distribution and $t_{1-\alpha/2,n-1}$ be the $1-\alpha/2$ quantile, so that $\alpha/2 + 1 - (1-\alpha/2)=\alpha$ of its probability is omitted (symmetrically) at both tails.  Then **a symmetrical prediction interval is**

$$\mathcal{I}_{\alpha, n}(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n) = \big[\bar Y + t_{\alpha/2,n-1}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}s_y, \bar Y + t_{1-\alpha/2,n-1}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}s_y\big].$$

It has the following defining property:

> Before observing *any* of $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n, Y_{n+1}$, the chance that $Y_{n+1}$ lies within the interval $\mathcal{I}_{\alpha, n}(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ is $1-\alpha$.

You will therefore conclude that **when $Y_{n+1}$ is outside the prediction interval, it likely was not drawn independently from a Normal distribution with the same mean as $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$.**

By selecting your *risk of a false conclusion* (under these hypotheses) to be a sufficiently small value of $\alpha$, you can assure it will be unlikely to identify $Y_{n+1}$ as "different" when in fact all $n+1$ of the $Y_i$ are independently drawn from the *same* distribution.

(This procedure sometimes is viewed as a Student $t$ test of $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ *versus* $Y_{n+1}$ using a "pooled variance" estimate.)

---

To demonstrate this procedure and to show it really works, I ran a simulation study using various values of $n=2, 10, 50$.  For each sample of size $n$, I computed prediction intervals of levels $\alpha=0.20, 0.05, 0.01$.  I then independently generated $Y_{n+1}$ from another Normal distribution with the same variance but a mean increased by $\delta$.  I recorded the proportion of times $Y_{n+1}$ fell in this interval.

Ideally, when $\delta=0$, the prediction interval should include $Y_{n+1}$ in $100-100\alpha\%$ of all cases.  Here are the results for $5000$ replications:

```
         2    10    50 Target
0.2  0.799 0.792 0.805   0.80
0.05 0.952 0.947 0.950   0.95
0.01 0.989 0.992 0.989   0.99
```

Rows correspond to $\alpha$ while columns correspond to $n$.  Evidently, the proportions are what we expect, regardless of the sample size: all values on the first row are very close to the target of $1-0.2=0.8$, all values on the second are close to $1-0.05=0.95$, and so on.

I then re-ran this simulation (using the same random number sequence) with $\delta=2$: that is, $Y_{n+1}$ was drawn from a normal distribution averaging two standard deviations more than the other $Y_i$.  This time, ideally, $Y_{n+1}$ would not lie within any of the prediction intervals--but that's too much to hope for, because two SDs isn't that much of a difference.  Here are the results:

```
         2    10    50 Target
0.2  0.593 0.313 0.246   0.80
0.05 0.903 0.598 0.502   0.95
0.01 0.982 0.838 0.740   0.99
```

The good news is that an interval with $\alpha=0.2$ and a largish sample of $n=50$ usually concluded $Y_{n+1}$ was different: $100 - 24.6 = 75.4\%$ of the time.  The bad news is that intervals with smaller $\alpha$ didn't detect a difference most of the time.

With a larger inherent difference of $\delta=4$ the results are

```
         2     10     50 Target
0.2  0.308 0.0094 0.0054   0.80
0.05 0.796 0.0834 0.0272   0.95
0.01 0.959 0.3090 0.1090   0.99
```

We can't accomplish much with a sample of $n=2$ and low $\alpha$, but otherwise in the vast majority of cases $Y_{n+1}$ is outside the prediction interval.

Studies like this give us a sense of the *power* of the prediction interval procedure to detect differences.  Use the results to select an appropriate value of $\alpha$ and, if you have the option, to determine how large $n$ needs to be.

```
set.seed(17)
n.sim <- 5e3                  # Simulation size
alpha <- c(0.20, 0.05, 0.01)  # Values of alpha to study
n <- c(2, 10, 50)             # Sample sizes
delta <- 0                    # Difference between the means
#
# Study various sample sizes `n`.
#
sim <- sapply(n, function(n) {
  Y <- matrix(rnorm(n*n.sim), n)   # The first `n` values
  Y.n1 <- rnorm(n.sim, delta)      # The n+1st value
  #
  # Study various levels `alpha` (for each given sample).
  #
  sapply(alpha, function(alpha) {
    #
    # Construct the prediction intervals.
    #
    kappa <- qt(alpha/2, df=n-1) * c(1,-1) * sqrt(1 + 1/n)
    Y.bar <- apply(Y, 2, function(y) mean(y) + kappa*sd(y))
    #
    # Test whether the interval includes the n+1st value.
    #
    covers <- (Y.bar[1,] - Y.n1)*(Y.bar[2,] - Y.n1) <= 0
    #
    # Report on the proportion of times during the simulation that the 
    # interval covers the n+1st value.
    #
    mean(covers)
  })
})
#
# Display a table of the results.
#
rownames(sim) <- alpha
colnames(sim) <- n
sim <- cbind(sim, Target=1-alpha)
signif(sim, 3)
```

Comment: Note that you assumed the new observation had the same variance and might only differ in the mean. @whuber

Comment: This is a nice answer. I don't like that you said it is not an outlier detection problem (boldface).  Any problem where you view a new observation as possibly from a different distribution can be viewed as outlier detection.  Outlier detection can be looked at philosophically because even extreme values have a possibility to come from the same distribution. I know it can be perceived differently since the n+1 st observation is not observed yet.  Usually outlier detection is used when you see all the data and pick the observation(s) are extreme and appear to come from a different distribution.

Comment: However once you see the observation outlier detection will probably reject the null hypothesis that it comes from the same distribution if the observation is extreme and will not reject if the observation conforms well to the original normal distribution.

Comment: I raise this because approaches depend on how you view the problem.  When estimation is the objective many statisticians choose robust estimation over outlier detection.

Comment: Also the OP raised the problem as testing a mean from a random sample.  It does not seem to be about prediction. I saw this as asking whether Y_(n+1) should be used in testing for the mean or be left out when it appears to come from a different population.

Comment: @Michael, thank you for the comments.  I meant "not outlier detection" in the sense of *we're not trying to identify which of $n+1$ values might be an outlier;* we're only deciding whether to *characterize* a predetermined one of the values as to whether it might be an outlier. One good way to do that is to predict that last value from the first $n$ values: if the $n+1$st doesn't fall within prediction limits, that's evidence it's different. The null hypothesis of course is that all $n+1$ are iid, so the questions of "same variance" or "differ in mean" don't even come up.

Comment: I get it. You read the question in a favorable way. I am not 100% sure that it was what the OP had in mind originally.